# How to make that GridView buttons update and delete just only visible for admins?

Tags: yii2

I am new to Yii2 and I have 3 kind of `user rights`:

`Admin`, `moderator` and `user`. I have my `GridView` and I don't want to show for the user the `Update` and `Delete` buttons, just only the `GridView`. How should I do that?

Here is my `actionCreate`, there is an input form:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Project();
    $model->scenario = Project::SCENARIO_CREATE;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Skelbimas sėkmingai pridėtas!'));
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I've tried to search the information according to this, but couldn't find useful ones. Thanks for any help or information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To accomplish this, you have to use the property [$visibleButtons](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$visibleButtons-detail) of you ActionColum class.

So:

```
'visibleButtons' = [
    'update' => Yii::$app->user->can('update'), // or whatever condition
    'delete' => Yii::$app->user->can('update')
]
```

and so on. Each Key on the visibleButtons array is the name of the button.

[Yii Framework's guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html)

Comment: Great answer! thanks. There's a typo there.`'visibleButtons' => [`

Answer (score 2):

```
        .........
        [
            'class'=>'yii\grid\ActionColumn',

            'template'=> '{view} {update} {delete} ',

            'buttons'=> [
                'update'=> function($url,$model) {
if (Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) {

                    returnHtml::a( '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url);

} 

                },

                'delete'=>function($url,$model,$key) {


if (Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) {
                        returnHtml::a('delete', $url);

} 

                },

            ],

        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be using the `'template'` attribute of youe `'ActionColumn'` like:

```
[
  ...
  'template'=> (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) ? '{view}' : '{view} {update} {delete}',
  ...
]
```

Please, bare in mind that even though this solution will hide the buttons for users with only `user` right, it won't prevent them of accessing update and delete action urls, so you have to check permissions also in the controller level.

Comment: Would the user be able to access action urls if I would generate 2 same `GridViews`? In one, I would delete those buttons manually, that `GridView` would be shown to the users, and the other (which has all the buttonts) - to the admin ?

Comment: If you want to configure the access control filter in you controller to grant/prevent access to the target controller actions: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-control-filter

Comment: The buttons are only direct accesses to those actions, with its corresponding parameters. The actions can also be accessed directly, for example introducing then in a browser