# How to make ActionColumn buttons visible just for admin?

Tags: yii2

I'm new to Yii2 and I need to make my `ActionColumn` class buttons of the `GridView` visible just only for `admin and moderator`.

I have 3 kinds of user rights:

```
const TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
const TYPE_SUPER = 1;
const TYPE_MASTER = 2;
```

And I need that my `GridView` would allow buttons just only for `TYPE_SUPER` and `TYPE_MASTER`. How can I achieve this?

Here is my `GridView` class:

Tried to do that with `visibleButtons` or `template`, but buttons are dissapearing for all the user rights. Thank you for the help

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
     'template' => '',
],
```

Comment: This question has been answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940842/how-to-make-that-gridview-buttons-update-and-delete-just-only-visible-for-admins/43944422#43944422

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make that GridView buttons update and delete just only visible for admins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940842/how-to-make-that-gridview-buttons-update-and-delete-just-only-visible-for-admins)

Answer (score 1):

You could use visible property

and if you have a rbac  management in your Yii2 app where your users have  role eg: admin you could

```
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'visible' =>  Yii::$app->User->can('admin'),
],
```

for your user "TYPE" this seems not related  to user http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html or http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html.. so you should explain better  what do you mean

Comment: `visible` not `visbile`